# JsonModel returning children, options and templates

Tags: php, angularjs, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am developing an app using Zend Framework 2 and Angular.js.

I have a Rest API module and use also a standard module returning JsonModel more specific things (the problem lives there).

In my module.config.php, I configured my view_manager this way:

```
'view_manager' => array(
'display_not_found_reason' => true,
'display_exceptions'       => true,
'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
'template_map' => array(
    'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
    'portal/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/portal/index/index.phtml',
    'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
    'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
),
'template_path_stack' => array(
    __DIR__ . '/../view',
),
'strategies' => array(
    'ViewJsonStrategy'
)
),
```

Before if I did this:

```
...
return new JsonModel(array('teste'=>true));
...
```

The return was:

```
{"teste":true}
```

But I do not know for what reason, return now looks like this:

```
{"children":[],"options":[],"template":"portal-admin\/transportadora\/verifica-cnpj-cadastrado","terminate":true,"variables":{"teste":true},"append":false}
```

I have looked any answers in the class reference, but found nothing.

Someone can help-me?

Thanks.

---

EDIT: I just want to return only "variables".

Comment: Have you thought about what you've changed since it used to work? Could you provide a snippet of the controller that's returning that response?

Comment: @Svengali I solved the problem right now. The problem was in my controller. Instead of extending the AbstractActionController, I was extending AbstractRestfullController. Very thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The problem was in my controller.

When you extend your controller to AbstractRestFulController, the return will be this (with children, template, variables). You just need to treat the result.

But in my case, I extended the wrong class, I needed to extend the AbstractActionController instead of AbstractRestfulController.

So the result was different.

Thanks for all!